# how can I convert an intmod to an int in pari/gp?

Tags: syntax-error, chinese-remainder-theorem, pari

I am performing chinese remainder theorem with pari/GP, and the result is an `intmod`.

Example:

```
x = Mod(25, 33)
```

`x` is an output of the Chinese remainder theorem.

But I want to compare 24 and `x`.

**How can I extract the "25" from `x` to be able to compare it with a regular `int`?**

Answer (score 1):

1. you can already compare `x` and 24: they are different

> ? x == 24
> %1 = 0

2. to extract the "25" from `x`, use `lift(x)`